# How to highlight frequency of keywords in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say, I am searching three phrases "Microsoft", "Facebook", "Google".

How can I make ES return the frequency of each terms in returned results?

Thank you!

Comment: So you want to get how many times this terms was in each found documents or all ?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for terms aggregations:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html

Essentially, it will bucket the results by what terms it finds

Comment: It depends if you want to return on each item or all items

Comment: I want to know relevance of each term in each returned results. For instance, for record 0: Microsoft: XXXX score, Google: XXX score.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you.  What do you mean when you say score?  Elasticsearch has a built in score:https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html

are you referring to that?

Answer (score 0):

I think the [`explain`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) API may help you. If you run the following query for instance:

```
GET /your_index/your_type/_search
{   
    "explain": true, 
    "query" : {
        "match": {
           "company" : "Google"
        }
    }
}
```

A result may be:

```
{
   "took": 9,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 2,
      "successful": 2,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
       "total": 1,
       "max_score": 11.7377,
       "hits": [
       {
            "_shard": 1,
            "_node": "n0eQxWrIIPYPlmcXA",
            "_index": "your_index",
            "_type": "your_type",
            "_id": "76991",
            "_score": 11.7377,
            "_source": {
            "company": "Google",
               "price": "2008"
            },
            "_explanation": {
                "value": 11.7377,
                "description": "weight(id:76991 in 6552) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
             "details": [
              {
                 "value": 11.7377,
                 "description": "fieldWeight in 6552, product of:",
                 "details": [
                    {
                       "value": 1,
                       "description": "tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:",
                       "details": [
                          {
                             "value": 1,
                             "description": "termFreq=1.0"
                          }
                       ]
                    },
                    {
                       "value": 11.7377,
                       "description": "idf(docFreq=2, maxDocs=138180)"
                    },
                    {
                       "value": 1,
                       "description": "fieldNorm(doc=6552)"
                    }
                 ]
              }
           ]
        }
     }
   ]
 }
}
```

Under the `_explanation` section you may see the document frequencies:

tf - how many times the term repeats in the specific scored document

idf - how many times the term repeats along all documents (what you are looking for, I guess)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you sir! I think you had a great example. Let's say the query is to search both Google and Microsoft. What I am interested in is that the frequency or relevance of each of these two phrases (google and microsoft) in each hit returned. How is this reflect in your example above? Thank you!

Comment: If you want to see "google" and "microsoft" in each hit. You may change the query as follows: 
GET /your_index/your_type/_search
{   
    "explain": true, 
    "query" : {
        "match": {
           "company" : { 
               "query" : "Google Microsoft",
              "operator" : "and"
        }
    }
}

This query will give you frequencies of both terms

Comment: Thank you sir! I added explain to the query. It explained how the score is calculated but not in a direct way the frequency of each phrase in each search result. In particular, my search was across 25 different fields with custom score. The returned JSON is really large. The JSON includes a lot of things that I actually didn't need. Any way I can just limit the explanation to relevance of search terms in each hit? Thank you!

Comment: Not that I know of. I guess you'll need to parse the JSON file using XPath or some other JSON path extraction method. Hope I have managed to help at least by showing you how to get phrases frequencies.